# android gcm project ID confusion

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I have few questions about the Android GCM

1. What is the use of Project ID/Sender ID in GCM.
2. Can i use the same project id for any number of server side apps with different application server code( Like one for giving Live scores, one for news app)
3. Why Google account is required?? How Google account is used in push notification.is it for authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to provide sender ID when you register your app/device for GCM. The RegID that you get back is associated with the sender, somewhere deep in Google's data. So that when the server pushes messages, Google's system can track back their authentication to the sender, and make sure that the app and the server really belong to the same entity.
2. Sure. Just reuse the authentication header.
3. You need a Google account to get access to the Google API console. Google needs a way to identify and authenticate you, an account owner, so that other people cannot play with your GCM settings.

EDIT: this is not official, but they claim the phone needs a Google account associated with it because GCM uses GTalk internally.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. so i can reuse the project ID to multiple senders who want to push messages to the client? and iam talking about the Google account in the phone is it required to have a google account registered in the phone if so how is it used by GCM?

Comment: That's in implementation detail that Google is not telling us. The word is that GCM piggybacks on GTalk, which requires a Google account.

Comment: A Google account is required on older devices, but not on devices running 4.0.4 or higher. You do still need Google services installed, however, as GCM reuses the same long-polling connection that is used by Play, Gmail, etc. which helps make it the most efficient push platform on Android.